# OS MAX FS 70 Exhaust Thread Size

Tags: engine, piston, thread

I was trying to figure out what kind of thread size the OS MAX FS 70 engine uses for its exhaust connector port. I am talking about the following (green circle)

[image: OS FS 70 image]

I could not find this in the manual, just the replacement parts but not what the thread size is. I have tried to use my measurement device and it seemed to be a 10mm hole, however using an M10 screw, it just slid into it like nothing. An M12 screw was too big. There are no M11 screws where I am from. I suppose it might be an imperial thread size, and I have absolutely 0 experience with that.

Does anyone happen to know what the thread size for that exhaust port is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this chart have your engine on it?

https://www.rcspecialties.net/products/engine_application_chart.pdf

There looks a similar engine number that has 11mm x 0.75mm exhaust thread -

[image]

Look like it is a metric fine 11mm.

I just did a search on google for “OS MAX FS 70 exhaust thread”